# Not a GROUP BY expression - OVER(PARTITION BY)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a query where it shows me the total per function per month but I am getting an error - not a GROUP BY expression.

I have this in the select statement -

```
sum(a.sched_hours) OVER(PARTITION BY d.function) AS total_hours
```

Anything I can do to show the correct results?

Comment: share details about the error and sample data and expected output

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the complete query; the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table(s); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an explanation of what the code should be doing; and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an analytic function, use the normal aggregation function instead:

```sql
SELECT function_name,
       TRUNC(dt, 'MM') AS month,
       SUM(sched_hours) AS total_hours
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       function_name,
       TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (function_name, dt, sched_hours) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2022-01-01', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2022-01-02', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2022-02-01', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2022-02-02', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2022-01-01', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2022-01-02', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2022-02-01', 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2022-02-02', 30 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FUNCTION_NAME | MONTH | TOTAL_HOURS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 01-JAN-22 | 20 |
> | A | 01-FEB-22 | 40 |
> | B | 01-JAN-22 | 40 |
> | B | 01-FEB-22 | 60 |

---

If you want a grant total for each function across all the months then nest the aggregation function inside the analytic function:

```sql
SELECT function_name,
       TRUNC(dt, 'MM') AS month,
       SUM(sched_hours) AS hours,
       SUM(SUM(sched_hours)) OVER (PARTITION BY function_name) AS total_hours
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       function_name,
       TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
```

Which outputs:

> | FUNCTION_NAME | MONTH | HOURS | TOTAL_HOURS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 01-JAN-22 | 20 | 60 |
> | A | 01-FEB-22 | 40 | 60 |
> | B | 01-JAN-22 | 40 | 100 |
> | B | 01-FEB-22 | 60 | 100 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1357ec9299e71ecc757d17378f59a000)*